# R linear models - category IDs as strings or ints

Tags: r, anova, linear-model, lme4-nlme

I am trying to fit a linear model (`lme4::lmer()`) to my data in R. I would like to look at a number of things, including "**scrambling**" of visual stimuli and "**intensity**" of the emotions portrayed therein. These things are stored the "**scrambling**" and "**intensity**" columns of my dataframe.

To ease your comprehension you may see a graphic plot of my data in [this other thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/76134/determining-best-approximator-based-on-repeated-measurements).

I have been told that linear model results can be compromised if category names are parsed as integers instead of strings by accident. But since these measures (**scrambling** and **intensity**) are kind-of quantitative, I am thinking it may be better to leave them as integers - or maybe even use both approaches separately.

I am however unsure how my interpretation of results should vary depending on whether or not my category IDs are passed as stings or ints.

Could anyone explain this to me?

Also would this differentiation still hold for when I use `stats::aov()` on the same data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question holds for all model types.

The key distinction is order.  Do the categories have an order?  If so, and there are many levels, using integers is valid.  If there is order and there is a small number of levels, it would be better to use a factor (in R) or a string because the small number of unique values will make it harder for the model to adequately estimate the effect on a continuum (the real numbers).

If there is no order, such as race coded as an integer, using integers will cause you to get results that make no sense.  They will be based on the order of the categories as they were in the data.

Comment: If you have an ordered factor the `clmm` function from the `ordinal` package will be useful.

Comment: if I have an order for two categories which is "easy" and "hard" - does that count as an order? Should I rather use strings or integers for that?

Comment: That would be order, but it would be better to leave it in the model as a string (or since you are doing R, you can set it as a factor).

Comment: what do you mean by "set it as a factor" - am I not doing that anyway by including it in the formula?

Comment: If you put a character variable in the model, R will treat it as a factor.  I was referring to the case where you have a coded set of values, say 0 and 1, that represent 'easy' and 'hard'.  In order to let R know that you don't want it to consider that as integers, you can use the `as.factor` function to let R know it is a categorical variable.